# A weird cipher inside video game

Tags: cipher, video-games

Recently a game named "[Ode to a Moon](https://colorfiction.itch.io/odetoamoon)" released.... during the gameplay there are several cipher sentences flashing on the screen. I was trying to decode them as a cryptography amateur(noob)，but still no clue.

I wonder if they are truly meaningful.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some of the ciphertext is in

> Morse code.
>  /.-../-.|
>  /L/N|
>
>  .--/.--6|
>  W/W6|
>
>  --- .-- --.. .-
>  O W Z A

Answer (score 2):

I think (but with cryptography/ciphers I can never be sure) that this is just for show. I wouldn't expect a game cipher to be too complicated (but there would be exceptions). there is a section that looks like hexadecimal, but it has codes that don't correspond to ASCII characters, so I think it's just meant to look like a cipher. This is just my suspicion, take it with a grain of salt.